# Velocity of a car in circular circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, velocity, vectors

Prior apology for any violation of rules and regulation and poor expression of question.

Statement:

> A racing car moves along a circular circuit with a constant speed of $20\text{ms}^{-1}$ in 5 second and covers half of the track.

Doubts:

A question on the velocity of the car at the starting point and at the instance the track was half completed, was asked. I was told that at the starting point, the velocity is $20\text{ms}^{-1}$ while on the halfway, the velocity is $-20\text{ms}^{-1}$. At this point, the answer is clear as the direction of travel has changed. However, because the question asked for velocity, and according to the formula, which should be: $$\text{velocity}= \frac{\text{displacement}}{\text{time}}$$ isn't that the velocity should be of a different value instead of $20\text{ms}^{-1}$ because it's a circular track.

Replies are greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here we are talking about instantaneous velocity. So,its -20 m/s. And the velocity will be always tangent to the circular track. So,it will be 20 m/s in magnitude every second. But the direction will be different so different values in x & y - axes

Comment: Right. If you want the "average velocity" over the time that the car drove around half the track, you would get a different answer - but in this case, the _instantaneous_ velocity is the "instantaneous" displacement over a very small amount of time.

Comment: the average velocity will be zero for one complete rotation

Comment: but its average speed will be 20 m/s.

Comment: no @WhatRoughBeast it won't be 20m/s. It will be different at every instan

Comment: @KishanKumar - read the OP. "A racing car moves along a circular circuit with a constant speed of 20ms −1". Speed is the magnitude of velocity, and does not (in this case) change with velocity direction.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast i didn't read that you told speed. i was mistsken. By the way i have also said the same thing in my answer.